# Formatting a retail Windows 10 USB key for personal use

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, rufus

**UPDATE**: It is indeed a read only flash disk. If someone knows of a way to make it write-able, I'm game to try it. Thanks all.

I've come across a retail Windows 10 USB key from a friend who only wanted the product license and gave me the physical USB drive to keep. I want to format it (to NTFS, if it matters), and use it as a personal USB drive, it's a nice 16 GB USB drive. I tried formatting with my favorite tool Rufus, which failed immediately. I took a look at Rufus's log, which gave me no leads as to what caused the issue. Unfortunately I am not at home and don't have the log with me, otherwise I would have uploaded it (I will update this question at a later point with the log). Anyone have any ideas as to what can cause this? I know with SD cards they have a physical lockout on the switch, but I'm not aware of any physical or software locks for a USB drive?

Comment: To ask the obvious question, did you already try formatting it within the built-in Windows `Disk Management` interface?

Comment: Given that it's distribution media, the thing may not be writeable at all. Honestly, it's possible that it's not in fact flash at all - it could very well be ROM of some type.

Comment: According to some Reddit thread it’s read-only, hardware-enforced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the USB key is not a "USB disk-drive" at all, but a "USB CDROM device".
Obviously you can't re-format a CDROM as that is by definition a read-only device.

Stick the key in a (already installed) Windows machine and check in Disk Administrator how it is detected by Windows. It will most likely list as CDROM device in stead of "removable drive".

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I will update you guys when I get a chance to test this theory at home.